# How to shrink table data to minimum with appropriate keys - TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and I have a complex query which pivots certain columns to get appropriate report of the data. The problem is, I am using join and certain cells which should be in the same, are in different row as the next picture shows:

[image: tsql pivot and select]

Rows, 19 and 20 should one row and cells in green should be also in that row, of course in the appropriate column.

In addition here is my query:

```
SELECT 

    Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4,
    [1] AS 'Kolona1', 
    [2] AS 'Kolona2', 
    [3] AS 'Kolona3', 
    [4] AS 'Kolona4', 
    [5] AS 'Kolona5',
    [6] AS 'Kolona6', 
    [7] AS 'Kolona7', 
    [8] AS 'Kolona8', 
    [9] AS 'Kolona9',
    [10] AS 'Kolona10', 
    [11] AS 'Kolona11', 
    [12] AS 'Kolona12', 
    [13] AS 'Kolona13',
    [14] AS 'Kolona14',
    [15] AS 'Kolona15',
    [16] AS 'Kolona16',
    [17] AS 'Kolona17',
    [18] AS 'Kolona18',
    [19] AS 'Kolona19',
    [20] AS 'Kolona20',
    [21] AS 'Kolona21',
    [22] AS 'Kolona22'

FROM   

(SELECT 
    v.Key1, v.Key2, v.Key3, v.Key4,
    v.Field1, r.Field2, v.Field3

    FROM MYDB.dbo.MY_TABLE_1 AS v

    INNER JOIN MYDB.dbo.MY_TABLE_2 AS r
    ON r.Key1 = v.Key1) as [P]  

PIVOT  
(  
    Max (Field2)  
    FOR Field1 IN (
        [1], [2], 
        [3], [4], 
        [5], [6], 
        [7], [8], 
        [9], [10], 
        [11], [12], 
        [13], [14], 
        [15], [16], 
        [17], [18], 
        [19], [20], 
        [21], [22])  
) AS pvt
```

I should display all dates for the same 4 keys in front in one row.

Comment: In general, you need to have your query employ the a `GROUP BY` to aggregate rows. However without providing the reason *why* rows 19 and 20 should collapse, no specific answer is possible.

Comment: you can create a sql fiddle for us with test data, then we might able to help you out :)
dbfiddle.uk or sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill which agregate function should I use? Those are strings which should collapse in one row

Comment: Update your question with reasons for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the outer SELECT is still SELECT so you can add GROUP BY or other stuff that come with it. Therefore I managed to get what I want by grouping the outer SELECT with my custom conditions. I managed to replace my own field names with some more general. Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    Key1, Key2, 
    Key3, Key4, 
    Key5, Key6, 
    Key7, Key8, 
    Key9, Key10,

    Max([1]) AS 'controlCode1',
    Max([2]) AS 'controlCode2', 
    Max([3]) AS 'controlCode3', 
    Max([4]) AS 'controlCode4', 
    Max([5]) AS 'controlCode5', 
    Max([6]) AS 'controlCode6', 
    Max([7]) AS 'controlCode7', 
    Max([8]) AS 'controlCode8', 
    Max([9]) AS 'controlCode9', 
    Max([10]) AS 'controlCode10',
    Max([11]) AS 'controlCode11', 
    Max([12]) AS 'controlCode12',
    Max([13]) AS 'controlCode13',
    Max([14]) AS 'controlCode14', 
    Max([15]) AS 'controlCode15', 
    Max([16]) AS 'controlCode16', 
    Max([17]) AS 'controlCode17',
    Max([18]) AS 'controlCode18', 
    Max([19]) AS 'controlCode19', 
    Max([20]) AS 'controlCode20',
    Max([38]) AS 'controlCode21', 
    Max([39]) AS 'controlCode22' 

FROM 

    (SELECT distinct 
        v.Key2, v.Key3, 
        v.Year, v.Key6 as Period, 
        k.Key1, k.Key4, 
        k.Key5, k.Key6, 
        v.controlCode, r.Name, 
        v.controlDate, v.Key7,
        v.Key8, v.Key9, 
        v.Key10 

        FROM MyDB.dbo.VT_TABLE_1 AS v 

        INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.KT_TABLE_2 as k 
        ON k.MyKey2 = v.Key2 AND k.MyKey1 = v.Key3

        INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.DATES AS r 
        ON r.controlCode = v.controlCode AND (v.controlCode < 21 OR v.controlCode > 37)

        WHERE v.Year = Year

     ) as [P]

                PIVOT 
                ( 
                    Max (controlDate)
                    FOR controlCode IN (
                        [1], [2],
                        [3], [4],
                        [5], [6],
                        [7], [8],
                        [9], [10],
                        [11], [12],
                        [13], [14],
                        [15], [16],
                        [17], [18],
                        [19], [20],
                        [38], [39])
                ) AS pvt

     GROUP BY 

     Key1, Key2, 
     Key3, Key4, 
     Key5, Key6, 
     Key7, Key8, 
     Key9, Key10;
```